# How to find the difference of two rows in an MySQL query result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SET @rowno= 0;
SELECT @rowno:=@rowno+1 AS `row`,`year`,`year_average` FROM(
/*get the average from the start of the 10 year period and the current period*/  

SELECT year,AVG(value) AS year_average FROM
/* get all records that have technical and trade school industry code */
(SELECT * FROM `allcesseries`
   WHERE series_id LIKE concat('%',(SELECT industry_code FROM `ceindustry` WHERE industry_name LIKE      '%Technical and trade schools%'),'%')) AS trade_schools
WHERE trade_schools.year = (2014-10) OR trade_schools.year = 2014
GROUP BY year) AS t
```

That returns the values

```
row | year | year_average
 1    2004   76.24
 2    2014   99.9
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the difference between row 1's year average and row 2's year average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MySQL

```
SELECT (
  (SELECT AVG(value)
  FROM allcesseries
  WHERE series_id LIKE concat('%',(SELECT industry_code FROM `ceindustry` WHERE industry_name LIKE '%Technical and trade schools%'),'%')
    AND year = 2014)
  -
  (SELECT AVG(value)
  FROM allcesseries
  WHERE series_id LIKE concat('%',(SELECT industry_code FROM `ceindustry` WHERE industry_name LIKE '%Technical and trade schools%'),'%')
    AND year = 2004)
) AS difference
;
```

should work. See [proof of concept](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c814/17/0). If not working in your case (or requiring tuning), please, provide a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with table structure and sample data.